# Akka Remote F# serialization problem causing server cannot start

Tags: f#, akka.net

I tried to use the following way to start a remote server on localhost, But I got the following exception about serializaton.
did I miss something? Is there something about configuration for packages?
This is the first time I try to use F# AKKA remote.
The sample server code is as follows:

```
#load "ref.fsx"
#load "Message.fsx"
open Message
open System
open Akka.FSharp
open Akka.Remote
open Akka.Configuration
open Akka.Serialization
let configuration = 
    ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(
        @"akka {
            actor {
                provider = ""Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote""
                debug : {
                    receive : on
                    autoreceive : on
                    lifecycle : on
                    event-stream : on
                    unhandled : on
                }
                serializers {
                    hyperion = ""Akka.Serialization.HyperionSerializer, Akka.Serialization.Hyperion""
                }
                serialization-bindings {
                    ""System.Object"" = hyperion
                }                
            }
            remote {
                helios.tcp {
                    port = 9002
                    hostname = localhost
                }
            }
        }")

let serversystem = System.create "Server" configuration



let server (mailbox:Actor<_>) =
    let rec loop () = actor {
        let! message = mailbox.Receive()
        match message with
        | Message(num, num1, str) -> printfn "Got a number %d %d %s" num num1 str
        | CreateDone(num, num1, str) -> printfn "Got a create %d %d %s" num num1 str
    }
    loop ()

let serveRef = spawn serversystem "server" server
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Here is the error I got? is there something with the configuration?

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Akka.Serialization.HyperionSerializerSettings' threw an exception.
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Hyperion, Version=0.11.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'Hyperion, Version=0.11.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Akka.Serialization.HyperionSerializer..ctor(ExtendedActorSystem system)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at Akka.Serialization.Serialization..ctor(ExtendedActorSystem system)
   at Akka.Actor.Internal.ActorSystemImpl.ConfigureSerialization()
   at Akka.Actor.Internal.ActorSystemImpl..ctor(String name, Config config, ActorSystemSetup setup, Nullable`1 guardianProps)
   at Akka.Actor.ActorSystem.CreateAndStartSystem(String name, Config withFallback, ActorSystemSetup setup)
   at Akka.Actor.ActorSystem.Create(String name, Config config)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0003>.$FSI_0003.main@()
Stopped due to error
Ruis-MacBook-Pro:project11 ruiniu$ dotnet fsi server.fsx
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Akka.Serialization.HyperionSerializerSettings' threw an exception.
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Hyperion, Version=0.11.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'Hyperion, Version=0.11.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Akka.Serialization.HyperionSerializer..ctor(ExtendedActorSystem system)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at Akka.Serialization.Serialization..ctor(ExtendedActorSystem system)
   at Akka.Actor.Internal.ActorSystemImpl.ConfigureSerialization()
   at Akka.Actor.Internal.ActorSystemImpl..ctor(String name, Config config, ActorSystemSetup setup, Nullable`1 guardianProps)
   at Akka.Actor.ActorSystem.CreateAndStartSystem(String name, Config withFallback, ActorSystemSetup setup)
   at Akka.Actor.ActorSystem.Create(String name, Config config)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0003>.$FSI_0003.main@()
Stopped due to error
```

Comment: It seems to me you're missing the `Hyperion` package.

Comment: Also, the Helios transport is outdated, and you should be using dot-netty.tcp in the Hocon, as shown [here](https://getakka.net/articles/remoting/transports.html). No additional packages is needed for that, but as mentioned you need Hyperion.

Comment: There is a bug in Hyperion that cause serialization of F# language elements with names containing characters outside of the ASCII range (e.g. type = BædFønnyCåde) to fail sporadically. Data in code (e.g. literal strings) does not seem to be affected. Seems to me the bug is caused by streamers not handling multi-byte characters correctly, possibly when these characters are split on some sort of data chunk boundary. If all your F# names are within the ASCII set, this won't be a problem.